# how to show all type of author posts in author page (SOLVED)

Tags: posts, pages, author, profiles

my site have multiple authors. I need to show  all type of author posts in author page that if visitors can see all posts of author when visitied his profile page.

this code

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>

<!-- Show custom post type posts from the author -->
<?php global $wp_query;
query_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'sikayet' ,
    'author' => get_queried_object_id(), 
    'showposts' => 10 )
); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ): ?>
    <h3>SIKAYETKLER <?php echo $curauth->first_name; ?>:</h3>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link: <?php the_title(); ?>">
<?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <p><?php _e('User has no custom posts'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: You should use `pre_get_posts` filter to change query parameters (like post type, number of posts per page, etc.) insted create new WP_Query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use WordPress [author template](https://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates) to show user posts ( `example.com/author/{user_name}` ) the best solution will be to change the main query via the [pre_get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) filter hook.

```
function se339534_author_any_post_types $query ) {

    // apply changes only for author archive page
    if ( ! is_author() || ! $query->is_main_query() )
        return;

    $query->set('post_type', 'any');
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'se339534_author_any_post_types' );
```

Comment: not worked.. i just need to show users other posts of author

Comment: What is the "author page"? I understand this is not the default template provided by WordPress and the address is not `/author/{user_name}`.

Comment: its defaut author template.. provided by WordPress...

Comment: So even if you add this code to the `functions.php` file, you still see only the list of "blog" posts?

Comment: probleblem is that.. author.php crated by me.. and this in page there are information and picture of author.. and i also want to display posts publised by this author that visitor can see this information. when they entered author.php

Comment: Can you paste the code from `author.php` file? You can skip the part that displays HTML.

Comment: there is no code in author.php its just beaver layout shorcode.. i design author.php with beaver layout.. i just need php code that parse and display author posts

Comment: Sample [template](https://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates#Sample_Template_File). Data is retrieved by the main [loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), you do not need to add any code. For displaying posts one by one, the code between `if ( have_posts() )` and `endif;` is responsible.

Comment: can you look this code i added

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean but this Wordpress function can display list of authors:

```
wp_list_authors( $args );
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_authors

You can use this one to display the posts of an author:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters

The author is the parameter.

Comment: thanks for you repy. but i want to show posts of author..  posts that written by author

Comment: Just edited my answer. I'm so sorry I didn't understand the question quite well. How about that?